# How to compute a map-to-screen transformation?

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping

Every projection calculation I have come across dealing with the Lambert Conic projection
converts the given Lat & Long to meters.
So now the magical question: **how on earth do you take the meters and convert to X, Y in pixels?**
I have a map of the US. The following is the projection info:

```
ullat=53.3638
ullon=-130.964
lrlat=18.2977
lrlon=-69.1058

sp1=0
sp2=39
rlon=-95.5
rlat=36.5
width=640
height=480
```

I converted this http://svn.onelab.eu/deprecated.PLCWWW/imports/import-001-head-04-24/plot-latlong/plot-latlong over to php, but get returned meters.
I am working on an open source project.  Most of the users will not be able to install Proj4, so that is not an option (even there the return is in meters).

Anybody?